# Rule for a regex enclosed by two /

Tags: ruby, treetop

How can I match everything between a pair of `/` characters with treetop? I would also like to match escaped `/` characters as well. For example, if I were to parse a "regex":

```
/blarg: dup\/md5 [0-9a-zA-Z]{32}/
```

The result would return:

```
blarg: dup\/md5 [0-9a-zA-Z]{32}
```

Comment: I think you want to get out the string from the regex. If so use `/blarg: dup\/md5 [0-9a-zA-Z]{32}/.source
# => "blarg: dup/md5 [0-9a-zA-Z]{32}"` .. I am not clear about the question, so I put it in the comment itself.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Treetop basic parsing and regular expression usage](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2404518/treetop-basic-parsing-and-regular-expression-usage)

Comment: What do you mean by "get"? You want to refer to it in subsequent operations? In that case, enclose the whole thing in ( .. ) and then you can refer to it with \1

Comment: Just want a regex compatible with the treetop rule format that matches /blarg: dup\/md5 [0-9a-zA-Z]{32}/

Comment: This is a valid question and should not be getting down votes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should match everything inside two `/` characters including escaped slashes. I'm using Ruby's `DATA` `__END__` feature so that everything can run in a single file.

Also, note that you can tag parts of a parsed expression and then use them as functions. In the example below I tagged `inside`. This could also have been accessed as `elements[1]` instead of being tagged.

This works similar to [matching a string](http://treetop.rubyforge.org/pitfalls_and_advanced_techniques.html) which you can find in the treetop docs.

```
require 'treetop'
Treetop.load_from_string DATA.read

parser = RegexParser.new

puts parser.parse('/blarg: dup\/md5 [0-9a-zA-Z]{32}/').inside.text_value

# => blarg: dup\/md5 [0-9a-zA-Z]{32}

__END__
grammar Regex
   rule regex
      '/' inside:('\/' / !'/' .)* '/'
   end
end
```

Comment: Will also use the DATA __END__ trick if my grammar does not grow much.